# How to transfer UIPickerView between two viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im very new to xcode.
Im getting the user to select from a UIPicker view and when they click a submit button it goes to the next screen and displays what they chose.
I got it to work with normal textboxes with segue code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let viewController2 = segue.destination as?
ViewController2 {
viewController2.textstr = textField.text
}
}
```

but i dont really know to apply the same formula with UIPickers, Segments and Steppers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var pickerValue = ""

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

      self.pickerValue = yourArray[row]
  }
}
```

And then:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "ViewController2" {
        if let dvc : ViewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2{
 
           dcv = self.pickerValue
     }
   }
}


  @IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2", sender: self)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass value from using thing code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var selectedPickerValue: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if let viewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            viewController2.selectedValue = selectedPickerValue
        }
        
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
        selectedPickerValue = //give value from you picker to this variable
        
    }
    
    
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var selectedValue: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

I hope you find it helpful. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Once:**

**This Will be picked your yourArray's Value**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController { 
   
      var pickerValue: String = ""   
      var yourArray: [String] = ["1","2","3"] 
  
      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()    

      }    
      
      func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

          self.pickerValue = yourArray[row]    
      } 
}
```

**Then You want to pass selected data first to second viewController using segue code **

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "SecondViewController" {
        if let nextPage : ViewController2 = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
           nextPage.selectedPickerValue = self.pickerValue
     }
   }
}

 @IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {  

         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: self)

   }
```

**SecondViewController look like it:**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedPickerValue: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```